# Make DIV clickable with 2 or more links

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have some difficulties with jQuery. I need to ma`div` or `section` clickable (add link to block element) and I already implemented some code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $(".clickable").click(function(){
            window.location=$(this).find("a.slide-link").attr("href");
            return false;
        });
    });
```

But when the block has 2 or more links - links in this block don't work correctly. Always redirect to `a.slide-link` url.

How I can solve this issue? 
Thanks!

Update

```
<section class="clickable">
    <div>
        <div class="description">
            <ul>
                <li>Lorem ipsum</li>
                <li>Lorem ipsum</li>
                <li>Lorem ipsum</li>
                <li>Lorem ipsum <a href="http://url1.com">here</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <a class="slide-link" href="http://url2.com">URL2</a>
    </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Can you show the full code of yours because i didnt get the question fully.

Comment: how do you decide which link to redirect to when user clicks on the `div` or `section` when it has more than 1 link?

Comment: @Varun I've updated description

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found answer

```
$(".clickable").click(function( event ) {
  var target = $( event.target );
  if ( !target.is( "a" ) ) {
    window.location=$(this).data("link");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Initial answer for initial question**

In case of multiple match, $(this).find("a.slide-link") gives array of nodes, hence, **.attr** does not work.

If you want to redirect to the 1st link then update your code to

```
$($(this).find("a.slide-link")[0])
```

**Updated answer for updated question**

Your anchor within the section will not work because of event bubbling. For reference - http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_bubbles.asp

What you have to do is stop event to bubble. For that add this in your js

```
$(".clickable a").click(function(event){
     event.stopPropagation();
});
```

Comment: For this to work he would have to add the `slide-link` class to the first link. Currently, it wouldn't give him an array of links. The reason it always "redirects" to the second link is because that is the only link being targeted.

Comment: @NightOwlPrgmr - At the time of answer there was no markup added to the question, hence, my answer stands correct, however, with the markup being added, I have to review my answer as well.

Answer (score 0):

If it's just the links you want to work within the section, but not clicking the section itself, then you can use the following:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".clickable a.slide-link").click(function(){
        window.location=$(this).attr("href");
        return false;
    });
});
```

Though only if you're planning on doing something other than simply going to that address, in which case the above code is the same as having no code..

If you want the outer section to be a link itself, you'd be better using an `<a>` tag for that too, and setting it to `display: block`. You can't nest anchor tags within other anchor tags for obvious reasons.

Answer (score -1):

You can select an anchor by its href value `$("a[href='www.myurl.com'")`

Read more about the selectors here. javascript uses the same selectors as regular CSS. given the browser supports the selector.
http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp